# fit_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Tags: python, arguments

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# Define the cleaning pipeline we defined earlier

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = message_cleaning)
tweets_countvectorizer = vectorizer.fit_transform(tweets_df['tweet'], dtype = np.uint8)
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
3
4 vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = message_cleaning)
----> 5 tweets_countvectorizer = vectorizer.fit_transform(tweets_df['tweet'], dtype = np.uint8)

TypeError: fit_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `dtype` argument to the constructor when creating the vectorizer object:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# Define the cleaning pipeline we defined earlier

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = message_cleaning, dtype = np.uint8)
tweets_countvectorizer = vectorizer.fit_transform(tweets_df['tweet'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The dtype parameter should be passed to the CountVectorizer's constructor:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# Define the cleaning pipeline we defined earlier

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = message_cleaning, dtype = np.uint8)
tweets_countvectorizer = vectorizer.fit_transform(tweets_df['tweet'])
```